# What AR/Lidar app is this?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, camera

During the [October 13, 2020](https://www.apple.com/apple-events/october-2020/) Apple Event announcing the iPhone 12, there’s a very quick demonstration of an app that uses AR or Lidar to scan a room and generate a blueprint with measurements. The demo is about one hour into the presentation, and only shows for about 10 seconds.

What is the name of this app? The only unique text visible on-screen is “InstaCAD” but I can’t find any iPhone apps when I search the web for that term.

[image]

Comment: How much research did you do? "ios lidar app" brings up dozens of hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the app called "Canvas: Pocket 3D Room Scanner" by Occipital!

Find it on the App Store here:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1514382369

You can watch their marketing video about the app here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_kG_kSYFUU

Note that the functionality in the video is only available on the iPhone 12 Pro and the 2020 iPad Pro (the models that have a LIDAR sensor).

And here's their web site clearly referencing that the app was featured in the mentioned Apple Event:

https://occipital.com

"(Featured in Apple Event October 13, 2020)"

Comment: Just a insiders tip about product announcements.  These are typically faked by the manufacturer to show the capabilities.  If they do use an actual app, they will have to acknowlegdge it (you can’t use someone else’s product in a *marketing* promo).  I’ve searched Occipital’s site and the Apple news resleases and can’t find any mention of this.  If Occipital’s product was used during a demo, you’d think they would be referencing it.

Comment: Ofcourse you can use some else's product in a marketing promo... Apple most probably asked Occipital for acceptance before including their app in their event. I think most smaller software companies would be happy to be included in the event - even just for 10 seconds and without a reference in a news release.

Comment: If you're sure it's not Occipitals app used - could you reference which app is used instead? - It seems to me to be clearly Occipitals app, as the user interface is exactly the same... including having the "InstaCAD" button in the same place alongside a "Scan" and "CAD" button.

Comment: I've just looked at their web site - and they even write on the front page that their app was  shown at the 13th of October Apple Event. I'll say it is pretty certain that it is the correct app.

Comment: I must have missed it...I stand corrected.  For the record you *can* use someone elses’ product in marketing material - you have to get permission -  I never said you couldn’t use it at all.

Comment: My exact words (I left it there for reference) “If they do use an actual app, they will have to acknowledge it..” Critical words being “if” and “will”. You found it and I acknowledged that.  You said “Apple most probably..”. No.  They *must* otherwise it’s copyright infringement and they will lose (and have).  The case was XtremeMac (settled).

Comment: Do you know if Apple asked for permission? - I guess you don't. I don't either. That's why I wrote that they "probably" did so - it would be the logical thing to do. Is it likely that Apple is comitting copyright infringement? - No. Is it completely impossible? - No. That's why I wrote "probably". You left out the last part of the sentence, which is the part I reacted to: "you can’t use someone else’s product in a marketing promo".

Comment: If you found the link of Occipital’s page (which you did)  permission was *granted* which infers that it was asked for whether directly or indirectly.  So,  technically, legally, and practically, they asked for permission.  There’s no “probably” about it.  Pulling a portion of a sentence out of context and saying that’s what you’re responding to that is insincere at best because that’s not what was stated and it’s clear.

Comment: I don't know why you're arguing on such a silly thing. As you can clearly see, I wrote the "probably" comment BEFORE reading their page. And still, it doesn't prove that Apple asked them before using it... so yeah, technically this is just silly to debate. Well, it wasn't clear to me - I do not like being called insincere or worse, so let's just stop this silly debate.

Comment: Because you’re arguing a point that is provably incorrect.  Probably is great BEFORE the page.  I’m respondng to the hair splitting you’re doing with me AFTER my mea culpa that I missed it, but your insistance that I be completely incorrect.  Again...Apple MUST get permission or they face legal libaility.  Period.  Take whatever you want out of context, it won’t change that fact.

Comment: You're really seeing something that is not there. I'm not insisting that you're completely incorrect... I'm just saying that Apple probably asked for permission before using this app in their event. I didn't have any evidence to say that they did (and I haven't seen it yet), so I still say that they probably asked for permission - it is highly likely that they did. I don't see why you care if they asked or not - the company is clearly very glad that they included their product in their event - I think almost any app developer would be.

Comment: “Did you know if Apple asked permission? I guess you don’t”. Do you remember what you typed? .”The answer by the way is, “Yes”

Comment: It's really great to hear you are so intimately involved Apple's business that you know whether or not they asked a specific company for permission. I guessed that you didn't know, but apparently you do. That's just super. I'm not at all understanding why we're spending time on that though.

Comment: I was actually in the VP’s office of XtremeMac when we were dealing with Apple’s legal team on this very issue.  So...yes...first hand knowledge.  I originally wanted to share some of the actual insider goings on, but you needed to assume I have no clue how any of this works.

Comment: I think you've totally misunderstood everything I've written. I have never once written anything about XtremeMac. I don't know the company at all. I'm talking about Occipital and their Canvas app.

Comment: OMG...XtremeMac was an example I used to substantiate my position of credibility